# SPSS PROCESS Macro by Hayes: Output not aligned since SPSS update to version 28

Tags: spss, process-macro

I use the SPSS macro PROCESS 4.2 from Hayes. Since updating to SPSS version 28 the output of the macro is not tab aligned anymore. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Would appriciate any help on how to get this output properly aligned again.

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS, go to Edit => Options, click on the Viewer tab, then change the Text Output font to “Courier New” and click the “Apply” button and then “OK” at the bottom of the window. (You should only need to do this once per computer and/or version of SPSS.)